# jmeter does not show the same page result as my browser's developer view

Tags: jmeter

jmeter http request results in a page that has div's, but the div's do not contain the rest of the http page.

If I use a browser's developer's view, I can expand the div's to see the rest of the http page results.

How do I get jmeter to show everything that is below the div's? The problem with getting all of the embedded resources is that the embedded resource shows ALL of the possible resulting page code for many different pages. I simply need the RESULT of ONE page to do testing that is specific to THAT page result.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to tick `Retrieve All Embedded Resources` on "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults%60)). If you're receiving resources you're not interested in you have `URLs must match` input which acts in 2 modes:

   - You can put specify URL pattern which will match your ONLY ONE PAGE
   - You can specify URL pattern which will not match specified pages, i.e. something like `^((?!google|facebook|cdn|yahoo|microsoft).)*$` will exclude requests originating from `google`, `facebook`, `cdn`, `yahoo` and `microsoft` domains.

     [image: JMeter exclude embedded resources]

     Patterns should be in form of [Perl-5 style regular expressions](https://www.pcre.org/). See [Excluding Domains from the Load Test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test) for more details.
2. As per [JMeter project main page](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

   > JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does

   So if you "divs" are populated by [AJAX calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) - JMeter will not execute them automatically, you will need to add the relevant HTTP Request samplers to mimic each AJAX call separately. As real browsers execute JavaScript asynchronously (in parallel) you should put these requests under [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md)
3. And finally to put everything together it makes sense to place all the requests under [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) so you could measure how much time does whole sequence take.